# realign code for readbility

Tags: regex, emacs, go

I have some code that looks like

```
Id string // uniq bid req id provided by the exchange
Fields []interface{} // array of field objects
User interface{} // user obj
Device interface{}
```

I know about the `align-regexp` function, and I use this to align my comments. This would output something like

```
Id string            // uniq bid req id provided by the exchange
Fields []interface{} // array of field objects
User interface{}     // user obj
Device interface{}
```

However, I would also like the types to be aligned properly. I was trying to figure out how I would be able to use `align-regexp` in order to accomplish this. Unfortunately, my regex skills are lacking.

I would like the output to look like

```
Id     string        // uniq bid req id provided by the exchange
Fields []interface{} // array of field objects
User   interface{}   // user obj
Device interface{}
```

I wouldn't mind if this was two separate function calls, as I could just write a function that could encapsulate them.

Also, I don't care if the solution ends up using `align-regexp`. This is just what I have been using for things like this thus far.

Comment: Take a look at the info page for `align-regexp` (default binding would be `C-h f align-regexp`- there is an optional repeat argument, which asks whether to repeat the rule throughout the line.

Comment: ...you can run `gofmt` over your code and it does exactly this. I am not sure how to set that up in Emacs but in Sublime Text I have it run on save - so that every time I save it formats the code like this.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead That works wonderfully. For anyone else, just add `(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'gofmt-before-save)` to your .emacs file and it works. Though, I would still like an answer to this for other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's maybe simpler than you think.

Are your types always one word ? Then you can use a space as the first regexp, and then align on the `//`. It does work with this example :)

Comment: Just tested in a couple different modes, and it seems to work in everything I use except go. I blame tabs for that. But, as mentioned above, `gofmt` on save is a better option for go.

Comment: cool !  you might as well use a proper regexp for tabs and spaces anyway, like `[:space:]` or `\s-` : http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Regexp#Syntax